# 408 Request Time-out Your browser didn't send a complete request in time.

Tags: 16.04

I have probelm in my `ubuntu 16.04.1 4.13.0-38-generic`, in chrome and firefox some website not openning and give me `408 Request Time-out` and of course in some app connecting to some server give me `Read timed out`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, these 400s are status codes and are client Error messages
408 Request Timeout
The server timed out waiting for the request. According to HTTP specifications: "The client did not produce a request within the time that the server was prepared to wait. The client MAY repeat the request without modifications at any later time."
In other words, your connection with the website "timed out."

1. First of all, you should check for the target link is right. Then, you can refresh the browser and try to connect the site again. You can successfully access to the targeted site if this is a temporary 404 error.
2. Try to visit some famous website like Google.com or Facebook.com and see whether you can normally access other pages. If you can successfully open other sites but only has the problem with the targeted site, the error may don’t come from yourself but that site. Just go to other sites.
3. If you can access to other sites like Google.com, but has a very slow speed, the cause may come from your network. Try to test your connection speed.
4. If the 408 error happens on a website with huge visits, the reason may be the server problems which are caused by the increased traffic. This situation general leaves when a part of users give up the site. In this case, you can wait for a moment and try to visit the site later.

Comment: in browsers using VPN solve my problem but in my ubuntu using VPN connection refused

Comment: your browser's web request is typically GET method to the data on the server side is not accepted. VPN requests with different HTTP methods. thats why VPN request is accepted.
Coming to the point, try above methods ensuring your VPN is not running